# warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'const int', possible loss of data

Tags: c++

I'm defining the '*' operator to work with a 'NumericArray' class template. The code is as following:

```
template <class T>
NumericArray<T> NumericArray<T>::operator * (const T& factor) const
{
    NumericArray<T> newArray(Size());
    for (int i = 0; i < Size(); i++)
        newArray[i] = factor * GetE(i);
    return newArray;
}
```

when I try to use a 'NumericArray' of type 'int' (NumericArray) with the '*' operator when the 'factor' argument is a double:

```
intArray1 = intArray1*2.5;
```

I get the following compiler warning:

```
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'const int', possible loss of data
```

and the 'factor' arg is truncated from 2.5 to 2 (an int) before it is multiplied against elements of the 'NumericArray' object. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I thought in C++ it was a simple matter of default protocol where int*double = double. Am I wrong? If not, why doesn't that apply in this case?

Comment: +1 It is a simple, but valuable question for a new user. Templates are not trivial!

Answer (score 9):

```
intArray1 = intArray1*2.5;
```

I guess `intArray1` is of type `NumericArray<int>` . If that is so, then `T` is `int`.  So in the above expression, `2.5` which is a `double` is going to be converted into `int`, as it is passed to the overloaded `operator*(const int&)` as argument.

That also means, 2.5 (double) becomes 2 (int) and `factor` is basically `2`. Loss of data!

One way to fix this is to use function template (as member of the class template) as:

```
template<class T>   //this is for class templatwe
template<class U>   //this is for function template
NumericArray<T> NumericArray<T>::operator * (const U& factor) const
{                                           //^^^^^^^ it is U now!
     //your code
}
```

Don't be surprised by two usage of `template` in the above definition. The comments say what they're for. If you understand that well, then you also understand that the parameter *now* is `U` instead of `T`, it can be independent of `T` and hence it can be whatever you pass to it as argument. No loss of data, as far as when passing the argument.

Now as you know the product of `int` and `double` turns out to be `double`, then why return `NumericArray<int>` from the function in case when you pass `double` to it? I think it makes more sense to return `NumericArray<double>` if the argument is `double`. So the following *seems* to be correct implementation:

```
template<class T>   //this is for class templatwe
template<class U>   //this is for function template
NumericArray<U> NumericArray<T>::operator * (const U& factor) const
{         //^^^ CHANGED
    NumericArray<U> newArray(Size());  //CHANGED HERE TOO!
    for (int i = 0; i < Size(); i++)
        newArray[i] = factor * GetE(i);
    return newArray;
}
```

**Wait! Is this correct now? What if `T` is `double` and `U` is `int`? The above has exactly the same problem as the previous one!**

So here is third attempt:

```
template<class T>   //this is for class templatwe
template<class U>   //this is for function template
NumericArray<decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>())> 
     NumericArray<T>::operator * (const U& factor) const
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>()) R; //define R
    NumericArray<R> newArray(Size());  //CHANGED HERE!
    for (int i = 0; i < Size(); i++)
        newArray[i] = factor * GetE(i);
    return newArray;
}
```

So the return type is :

```
NumericArray<R>
```

where `R` is:

```
decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>());
```

which depends on the type of the product of `T` and `U`. That is correct now, *at least* much better.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 (and even fixing that, I'm not holding out much hope for the return value of `GetE(i)` either).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Edited it with lots of additional stuff. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Nawaz, I appreciate it, but I was hoping to find a solution that wouldn't require me to re-declare and redefine all constuctors, functions and operators in my NumericArray template class to incorporate

Comment: Nawaz, I appreciate it, but I was hoping to find a solution that wouldn't require me to re-declare and redefine all constuctors, functions and operators in my NumericArray template class to incorporate the extra types 'U' and 'R'. Looks like there isn't one. Ah, the joyous rigidity of C++!

Comment: @user2736224: There is NO redefine. Just small changes. Or how else do you want to fix the issues? without changing anything?

Answer (score -1):

Your template code mandates that the argument and NumericArray elements have the same time, that is why C++ is truncating arg to 2 before multipying.

To fix that you should code something like

```
template <class U> template<class T>
NumericArray<T> NumericArray<T>::operator * (const U& factor) const
{
  /***/
}
```

Comment: why not? Please explain

Comment: you suggest the exact same thing!

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOO. See again!

Comment: I just had a typo in the template<u,T> instead of template<T> template<U>, but the idea of making the argument an independent template argument is the same. Post the right idea before you with a typo that is easy to fix. Update: Thank you for removing downvote